# PHP file_get_contents source code location

Tags: php

I would like to have a look at the source code of `file_get_contents`.

I've been googling for hours now but cannot find it or it's location in php download.

I downloaded php-5.4.15.

Does anyone know where I could find this?

Comment: php source code can be found on the PHP website at http://php.net/downloads.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can view (and more importantly, search) the PHP source online [here](http://lxr.php.net/).

The source for the current version of `file_get_contents` in the 5.4 branch is [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/file.c#512). As an added bonus, all names in the source are also linked to searches from which you can easily get to their definitions in turn.